# How make System.out.println collect links only with child p tags?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

How make System.out.println show only links with /p/ ? I'm trying to write a program that would display all links by hashtag on Instagram. I was able to parse all links with the "a" tag. How can I now select links to a photo where /P/ is available?

```
        String hashtag = null;

        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"+hashtag);


        String link_include= "/p/";
       List<WebElement> all_links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

             if (all_links.contains(link_include)){
                    //What do I need to write here for the variable to show links only with the /p/ ?can I use the append method? And How ?
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: only call System.out.print if that String is in the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a list of the `<a>` tags having a clild `<p>` tag you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  List<WebElement> all_links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[.//p]"));
  ```
- To print the link texts using *Java8's* `stream()` and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[.//p]")).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  List<WebElement> all_links = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//a[.//p]")));
  ```
- To print the link texts using *Java8's* `stream()` and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//a[.//p]"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```

Comment: Thank you, probably its my mistake but smth is wrong, there is nothing in console. My full code:https://pastebin.com/CstRgDbn.

Comment: But all tests passed successfully

Answer (score 0):

System.out.printlu(all_links.gettext());

Answer (score 0):

Someone might have a problem with this issue. If the code above my comments doesn't work, try something like this: // a [starts with (@href, '/ p /')]. Remember that you need to add a scroll to get more links than in the first div.